# How to display records while omitting repetitive fields in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have the following record I am retrieving from Web API:

```
FullRecord
_______
RecordID
RecordDate
PersonName
RecordNote
LineOrder
```

The data comes from a Web API in JSON format.

The content is something like this:

```
RecordID    RecordDate  PersonName  RecordNote  LineOrder
1           10/25/2016  John Doe    test1       1
1           10/25/2016  John Doe    test2       2
1           10/25/2016  John Doe    test3       3
2           10/25/2016  Jane Doe    testing23   1
2           10/25/2016  Jane Does   testing27   2
```

I am displaying it withi my AngularJS application as follows:

```
 <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="Record in Records">
                    <td>{{Record.RecordID}}</td>
                    <td>{{Record.RecordDate}}</td>
                    <td>{{Record.PersonName}}</td>
                    <td>{{Record.RecordNote}}</td>
                    <td>{{Record.LineOrder}}</td>
        </tr>
 </tbody>
```

This way the first 3 fields are repeating for each record with the same record ID. I was wondering if I can somehow only display RecordID, RecordDate, and Person Name in a row if it is not repeating.

For example:

```
RecordID    RecordDate  PersonName  RecordNote  LineOrder
1   10/25/2016  John Doe    test1       1
                            test2       2
                            test3       3
2   10/25/2016  Jane Doe    testing23   1
                            testing27   2
```

How can I accomplish that with Angular?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `unique` filter to achieve this. This is not part of Angular, but is available in Angular UI [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-OLDREPO/blob/master/modules/filters/unique/unique.js)

```
<tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="Record in Records | unique:'RecordId'"">
                    <td>{{Record.RecordID}}</td>
                    <td>{{Record.RecordDate}}</td>
                    <td>{{Record.PersonName}}</td>
                    <td>{{Record.RecordNote}}</td>
                    <td>{{Record.LineOrder}}</td>
        </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Define the filter like so:

```
.filter('unique', function () {

 return function (items, filterOn) {

if (filterOn === false) {
  return items;
}

if ((filterOn || angular.isUndefined(filterOn)) && angular.isArray(items)) {
  var hashCheck = {}, newItems = [];

  var extractValueToCompare = function (item) {
    if (angular.isObject(item) && angular.isString(filterOn)) {
      return item[filterOn];
    } else {
      return item;
    }
  };

  angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
    var valueToCheck, isDuplicate = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < newItems.length; i++) {
      if (angular.equals(extractValueToCompare(newItems[i]), extractValueToCompare(item))) {
        isDuplicate = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!isDuplicate) {
      newItems.push(item);
    }

  });
  items = newItems;
}
return items;
};
});
```